# New value on gridview edit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How to get the new value of boundcolumn(default textbox on edit mode) when the gridview is in edit mode on external button click.

```
if (grdMappingLog.HeaderRow != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < grdMappingLog.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(grdMappingLog.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text);
            }
        }
        foreach (GridViewRow row in grdMappingLog.Rows)
        {
            DataRow dr;
            dr = dt.NewRow();

            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                dr[i] = row.Cells[i].Text.Replace(" ", "");
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: Check the edited code part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
TextBox txt= (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0];
Response.Write(txt.Text);
```

**Cells[2]** retrive TextBox in column 2 of gridview1

Comment: I am using boundfield not templatefield

Comment: Is it possible to achieve bulk edit in gridview with boundfield only